# Which Java package contains advanced mathematics functions?

Tags: java, math, package, mathematical-optimization

Can anyone tell me which package do I need to import to use mathematical functions such as derivatives, sums, exponential. I'm going to do a project about the Expectation and Maximization Algorithm related to Gaussian Mixture.

What other packages do you recommend to use?

I'm a total beginner with Java programming and this is my first project as a freshman.

Comment: You're looking for the Math class, I presume?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: @Stultuske I don't believe the Math class has those functions...

Comment: @Stultuske No, that class does not handle complex operations such as those the OP wishes to use.

Comment: I'm not certain if the math class does derivatives etc though - you may need an external library.

Comment: that's the point. for some stuff, he 'll need an external library. for some other, he might have to write his own code.

Comment: May https://mahout.apache.org/ provide the algorithms you need.

Answer (score 5):

The [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library contains many advanced mathematical functions and algorithms that you can use. It has a section, [Numerical Analysis](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html) which have many algorithms for common math problems, such as **roots finding**, **derivatives** and **integrals**.

Please refer to the hyperlinks for more information and documentation about the library.

---

The workflow of computation of a derivatives of an expression y=f(x) is the following one.

First we configure an input parameter x of type DerivativeStructure so it will drive the function to compute all derivatives up to order 3 for example.

Then we compute y=f(x) normally by passing this parameter to the f function.

At the end, we extract from y the value and the derivatives we want.

As we have specified 3rd order when we built x, we can retrieve the derivatives up to 3rd order from y.

```
int params = 1;
int order = 3;
double xRealValue = 2.5;
DerivativeStructure x = new DerivativeStructure(params, order, 0, xRealValue);
DerivativeStructure y = f(x);
```

You can then, get the derivatives:

```
System.out.println("y    = " + y.getValue();
System.out.println("y'   = " + y.getPartialDerivative(1);
System.out.println("y''  = " + y.getPartialDerivative(2);
System.out.println("y''' = " + y.getPartialDerivative(3);
```

Answer (score -8):

You don't need to import anything, the static class `java.lang.Math` will satisfy your needs.

Example:

```
double result = Math.sqrt(112);
```

Comment: The `Math` class does not have methods for the operations OP wants.

Comment: Please reformulate the question, it clearly specifies "Which is the package from Java where I can use math functions?". The Math class provides math functions, therefore my answer solves his problem.

Comment: You're missing the "**such as derivatives, sums, exponential.**" part. So your answer in fact does *not* solve his/her problem.

Comment: @ta.speot.is and Mati: Please keep comments constructive and on-point.